# Implementing scrolling on an infinite grid for Conways game of life using HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, optimization, scroll, html5-canvas, conways-game-of-life

I've set up an 'infinite' grid for Conway's Game of Life using a Set object to store only the coordinates of active cells. I've implemented scrolling by applying a fixed offset to the X and Y coordinates of active cells for horizontal and vertical scrolling, respectively. However, this approach becomes quite resource-intensive as the Set grows larger, and want to know if there is a better solution that is also not too complicated. I've included the code below. My solution is pretty simple so I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I've only encountered solutions relating to memoization algorithms. Any suggestions on how to optimize this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
const Scroll = {
    SCROLL_INCREMENT: 5,

  up: function (game, event) {
    if (event.key !== 'ArrowUp') { return; }
    this.scrollCells(game, 0, this.SCROLL_INCREMENT);
  },
  down: function (game, event) {
    if (event.key !== 'ArrowDown') { return; }
    this.scrollCells(game, 0, -this.SCROLL_INCREMENT);
  },
  left: function (game, event) {
    if (event.key !== 'ArrowLeft') { return; }
 this.scrollCells(game, this.SCROLL_INCREMENT, 0);

  },
  right: function (game, event) {
    if (event.key !== 'ArrowRight') { return; }
    this.scrollCells(game, -this.SCROLL_INCREMENT, 0);
  },
  scrollCells: function (game, dx, dy) {
    const updatedCells = new Set();
  
    for (const coordinate of game.activeCells) {
      const [x, y] = coordinate.split(",").map(Number);
      const newX = x + dx;
      const newY = y + dy;
      updatedCells.add(`${newX},${newY}`);
    }
    game.activeCells = updatedCells;
  }
};
```

I tried using ctx.translate() which also requires applying an offset to the set of activecells and draw them accordingly, which is not much different to my previous solution.

Comment: You should differentiate between "view coordinates" and "world coordinates". The world coordinate system would not need shifting when you scroll. The view coordinates would shift, but they would not be stored -- only calculated on-the-fly during the rendering. So your `game.activeCells` should not be updated after a scroll event (assuming world coordinates). Just add the scroll offset (total dx, dy) when you render.

Comment: @trincot  can you provide more details? I'm uncertain if I grasp the concept completely. Are you suggesting that instead of directly modifying the cell's coordinates, I should simply adjust the location during the rendering process? If that's the case, wouldn't it essentially amount to the same thing, given that the offset isn't being stored, in this case and hence amount to the same performance?

Comment: It would save you from creating a new set. If you do it during the rendering, then for each location on the screen you calculate which cell is to be visualised there (if there is data for it -- look in set), and then display it -- no need to update a set. Moreover, you "only" do that calculation for cells that are in view of the screen, not those outside of it.

Comment: but wouldn't performance be the same regardless?

Comment: Sure, in terms of time complexity it wouldn't change, as obviously you have anyway to visit live cells and their neighbors to produce a next generation. But saving on a set, and saving on the number of cells to read when rendering can surely reduce execution time. Obviously it makes a difference whether you update a set or not, and whether you visit billions of cells, or only the number of cells that are visible on the screen.